# Solr facet.query for query, without filter.query

Tags: solr, filter, facet

Is there any way to get *facet.query* results only for the main query, without a *facet.filter* query.
For example, I have the request:

```
q=item_id:* 
&fq=item_param:3 
&facet.query=item_param:1
&facet.query=item_param:2
```

Is it possible to get facets from all item results (`item_id:*`), not from *fq* (`item_param:3`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by [tagging and excluding filters](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_0/faceting.html#tagging-and-excluding-filters). First, you want to tag your filter queries with a tag (e.g., *filters*):

```
fq={!tag=filters}item_param:3
```

Second, tell your facet queries to ignore the tag you used for the filters:

```
facet.query={!ex=filters}item_param:1
facet.query={!ex=filters}item_param:2
```